# Boundary conditions required to get a unique solution to Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, boundary-conditions

If we are considering the scattering of an electron plane wave from a crystal specimen, we could start with the time-independent Schrodinger equation (TISE) as our governing equation:

$$ \{\nabla^2 + 4\pi^2 [U(\textbf{r}) + K^2]\}\Psi(\textbf{r}) = 0$$

where $U(\textbf{r})$ is the crystal potential and $K$ is the wavenumber. **How do we specify boundary conditions** in order to get a unique solution for $\Psi(\textbf{r})$ (up to a phase factor)?

From a physical standpoint, we know that $\Psi(\textbf{r})$ could be broken down into plane wave components "above" the specimen (i.e. in the direction of the source of electron illumination) and "below" the specimen (i.e. on the opposite side from the illumination) as follows:

- **Above:** only the incident electron beam in the illumination direction plus back-scattered beams in the opposite direction, and
- **Below:** only the forward-scattered electron beams emerging from the opposite side of the crystal specimen.

**Is this sufficiently specified? And how could it be specified "more clearly", i.e. in a more mathematical way (rather than just words) that could actually be leveraged as part of a solution method?**

When the problem is stated in *integral form*, it seems much more concise and straightforward:

$$ \Psi(\textbf{r}) = \exp(2\pi i \textbf{K} \cdot \textbf{r}) + \pi \int d\textbf{r}' \frac{\exp(2\pi i K |\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}'|)}{|\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}'|} U(\textbf{r}') \Psi(\textbf{r}')$$

Here, it seems that the boundary conditions are effectively accounted for with the first plane wave term (showing that with zero potential, the solution is just the incident plane wave illumination) as well as the choice of the *outgoing* Green's function (which represents the physical effect of spherical waves scattering outwards from the potential).

**Can the boundary conditions stated as part of the differential equation formulation above be made clearer, and be reconciled with the integral formulation?**

Comment: It seems like you are not asking about quantum problems at all, but rather asking about PDE in general. This is a very well known thing about PDE and their boundary conditions; integral equations are where you can specify the boundary conditions along with the integral itself, not PDE. You are simply supposed to state the boundary condition separately from the PDE.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, I think that the OP’s question is more about motivating physically the choice of boundary conditions which is why the quantum setting is relevant.

Comment: @LPZ But if that is the case, he could have just extracted the boundary condition from the integral form and be done with it. I am not sure what even is the question.

Comment: Thanks @naturallyInconsistent and LPZ, you're both right. In the end I'd like to get more insight into this as a PDE problem and how those should be stated "properly" including the boundary conditions; but in this case I'm not sure how these boundary conditions (arising from the physical scenario) should be framed. I'm also not sure how to "extract" the boundary condition from the integral form and state it clearly in the differential form. The way I've stated it above doesn't "feel right".

Comment: That is not an obvious nor easy thing, so don't feel bad. In this case the integral form is much easier to write down than it is to state the boundary conditions. But now you know where to look for the answer.

Comment: Oh... Do you mean I should just substitute the boundary locations (entrance and exit surfaces) for $\textbf{r}$ in the integral form above and that defines the boundary conditions?